# using Eclipse for Android development - cant find jarsigner.exe4

Tags: android

Now I am at the stage of preparing my android app for publishing I discover that jarsigner.exe is not on my hard disk ( done a full search)  I have the jave sdk and java jre and keytool.exe but no jarsigner.  I have googled and followed thro links that appeared to offer download of jarsigner but none of them acftually do.   I have been to the official java site but cant find an option to download this file - can anyone help?

I am using Eclipse and thought that when I did the various downloads for Eclipse, Android and Java I would have all the necessary files.

From the reading I have done it seems that the Eclipse export wizard only prepares debug signed .apk and I must follow the unsgned/keytool/jarsigner route to get a distrbutable file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need it.

Right-click on the project in the Package Explorer view, in the popup menu choose Android Tools/Export signed application package.

Comment: I did that originally and the apk was rejected by Google on the basis that it was a debug apk.

Comment: Open the manifest, under <application> element, find the android:debuggable attribute, and remove it. Or set to false. "Export signed package" worked for me since day one, I've got 4 apps on the Market.

Comment: Thanks Seva that worked.   There was no entry in the Manifest for debuggable and as far as I can recall the Android Developer site doc on preparing the app made no mention of it.

Answer (score 1):

In the directory of the JDK (not JRE).

%JDK_HOME%\bin\jarsigner.exe

You can download it from here - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html