# Getting error message while opening apk file in eclipse - Cannot find jarsigner which is required to test the apk

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, robotium

Getting error message while opening apk file in eclipse - Cannot find jarsigner which is required to test the apk. 
I am trying to create new Robotium test in eclipse but i am getting "Cannot find jarsigner which is required to test the apk." message popup when trying to select apk

Answer (score 0):

You Might get Solution of your problem here.

[Can't find JarSigner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606403/using-eclipse-for-android-development-cant-find-jarsigner-exe4)

Else You can try to download fresh JDK from Oracle website .. Here is the link for same.
[JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)